# MPI Odd/Even Compare-Split Deadlock

Tags: parallel-processing, deadlock, mpi

I'm trying to write an MPI version of a program that runs an odd/even compare-split operation on n randomly generated elements.

Process 0 should generated the elements and send nlocal of them to the other processes, (keeping the first nlocal for itself). From here, process 0 should print out it's results after running the CompareSplit algorithm. Then, receive the results from the other processes run of the algorithm. Finally, print out the results that it has just received.

I have a large chunk of this already done, but I'm getting a deadlock that I can't seem to fix. I would greatly appreciate any hints that people could give me.

Here is my code http://pastie.org/3742474

Right now I'm pretty sure that the deadlock is coming from the Send/Recv at lines 134 and 151.  I've tried changing the Send to use "tag" instead of myrank for the tag parameter..but when I did that I just keep getting a "MPI_ERR_TAG: invalid tag" for some reason.

Obviously I would also run the algorithm within the processors > 0 but I took that part out for now, until I figure out what is going wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** I've written a smaller test case, that doesn't contain any CompareSplit operations, but is still deadlocking. http://pastie.org/3744691

I fixed the above test case by changing the tag at line 83 from "myrank" to "tag".
Well the test case works, but when the actual algorithm is added in like in my program it deadlocks..

So, I think I've narrowed the deadlock down to this chunk of code. **It looks to be the Sendrecv under the else.**

```
for (i = 1; i <= npes; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 1) // odd phase
      MPI_Sendrecv(elmnts, nlocal, MPI_INT, oddrank, 1, relmnts,
                           nlocal, MPI_INT, oddrank, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    else
      MPI_Sendrecv(elmnts, nlocal, MPI_INT, evenrank, 1, relmnts,
                           nlocal, MPI_INT, evenrank, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

    CompareSplit(nlocal, elmnts, relmnts, wspace,
                 myrank < status.MPI_SOURCE);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag error was because tags have to be positive integers in the range from 1 to some implementation-dependant maximum which is guaranteed to be at least 32k.

The deadlock is pretty easy to understand; look at what the non-rank zero processes are doing:

```
  else {
    // The rest of the processes
    // Receive nlocal randomly generated elements from process 0
    MPI_Recv(elmnts, nlocal, MPI_INT, 0, tag, comm, &status);

    qsort(elmnts, nlocal, sizeof(int), IncOrder); // does it matter where we sort at?

    // Send results back to process 0
    MPI_Send(elmnts, nlocal, MPI_INT, 0, myrank, comm);
  }
```

So they're doing one receive, and one send back.   But processor 0 is doing much more than this; it sends everyone their data, then executes a bunch of send-receives to process 1 (evenrank) and MPI_NULL_PROC (oddrank).   But the send-receives to evenrank are noops, and the the send-recieves to process 1 will never be answered because process 1 isn't doing the same thing.

I think you need to move that part of the algorithm outside of the `if (rank == 0)` test.

Comment: Ok, I want Process 0 to also be involved in the algorithm which is why I had that block in the if (rank == 0). So I want each process to run CompareSplit on their nlocal elements. I will try moving the algorithm outside of the if (rank == 0) test like you said and see what happens. Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean something like this? http://pastie.org/3745277  Because that doesn't make sense to me, since we should be sending the results back to process 0 after CompareSplit has been ran..also process 0 shouldn't have to send/receive with itself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling `MPI_Sendrecv` [line 113], but there are no process with the `oddrank` rank to answer it, because `oddrank eq -1`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look through my program. I knew that oddrank was going to be -1 ahead of time for processor 0 and I already added in sometime to fix that. Look at line 109, oddrank = MPI_PROC_NULL;  This is already stopping the problem you are referring too. I apologize for not commenting that line better.

Comment: also see Edit in original post

Comment: so it looks to be the evenrank MPI_Sendrecv, any idea why?